# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_RKLogCoreDataError"

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone, mac, build

Bom dia, sempre que estou tentando realizado o build da minha aplicação, na etapada de *Linking* acontece o erro de **Undefined symbols for architecture**

Segue o erro com mais detalhes:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>       "_RKLogCoreDataError", referenced from:
>         ___33-[RKEntityByAttributeCache load:]_block_invoke in libRestKit.a(RKEntityByAttributeCache.o)
>         ___43-[RKManagedObjectImporter finishImporting:]_block_invoke in libRestKit.a(RKManagedObjectImporter.o)
>       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image: Undefined symbols for architecture i386]

Vocês já passaram por alguma situação semelhante?

Estou usando o Xcode 6.4 (6E35b)